# Boostrap Dropdown Login Menu doesnt work on other pages

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

For some reason my bootstrap drop down login menu doesnt work on subpages.

nav.php

```
   <!-- The drop down menu -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav list-inline">
          <li><a href="http://gotospectrum.com/Login/registerform.php">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign In <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
              <!-- Login form here -->
              <form action="http://gotospectrum.com/Login/connectivity.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                    <input id="user" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="user" size="30" placeholder="username" required/>
                    <input id="pass" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="pass" size="30" placeholder="Password"required/>
                    <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" />
                    <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>

                    <input class="btn btn-success" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 6px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
              </form>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul
```

I have session_start(); at the top of my pages however its still not pulling up the drop down menu.

I have a feeling this is the problem

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign In <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
```

the `href="#"` pulls up when i click the drop down link. in my sub pages.

Comment: my guess, a tag is open tags `< />` can be div, span, label, any element take page view source in firefox and see if there is any red line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup works right away -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vuuohp3a/**

However, I can see in the link to "signup" that you are refering to the `/root/js` path even though you are located in `/root/subpage/` :

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

`/Login/js/jquery.js` does not exists, causing "*$ is not defined*"   (neither jQuery or bootstrap is loaded) you should refer relatively to the parent directory :

```
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

or use absolute paths :

```
<script src="https://yoursite.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your website for security errors.

I know im off topic here but was just testing the website you are creating and you are doing some wrong stuff from the point of view of the website's security:

http://gotospectrum.com/Login/register.php?regname=&regemail=&regpass1=&regpass2=

This link when someone tries to register shouldnt appear on the adress bar at all, dont use GET as method for the form but POST this way the data wont appear on the url.

This is one of the simpliest rules to follow, havent tested your webiste for other problems just found it and reported it here.

Comment: i see what i did there however it doesnt seem as easy as changing $_GET to $_POST? any suggestions?

Comment: Not get to post but:

<form method="get" action=""> should be changed to <form method="post" action=""> on register.php